# Convert seconds since 01-01-1900 to timestamp in Brazil

Tags: java, datetime

I'm managing devices that report their system clock as seconds since midnight 01-01-1900.
I need to convert this into a timestamp.

So far, I'm doing this as follows:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TestTime
{
  // Pass seconds since 01-01-1900 00:00:00 on the command line
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // ---------------------
    // Create time formatter
    // ---------------------
    SimpleDateFormat format;
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    // ---------------------------
    // Compose 01-01-1900 00:00:00
    // ---------------------------
    Calendar cal;
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // -------------------
    // Show what we've got
    // -------------------
    System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Add the seconds as passed on the command line
    // ---------------------------------------------
    long secs = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    while (secs > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
      cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
      secs -= Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int)secs);

    // -------------------
    // Show what we've got
    // -------------------
    System.out.println(args[0] + " corresponds to " + format.format(cal.getTime()));

  } // main

} // class TestTime
```

When running this on my local PC (Italy, Windows 7), I get the following:

```
java -cp . TestTime 3752388800
1900-01-01 00:00:00
3752388800 corresponds to 2018-11-28 10:13:20
```

This is perfectly correct.
I get the same results when running this on a Linux machine (still in Italy).

However, running the very same program on a Linux machine in Brazil, I get different results:

```
java -cp . TestTime 3752388800
1900-01-01 00:00:00
3752388800 corresponds to 2018-11-28 11:19:48
```

Whatever value I pass on the commandline, the difference is always 01:06:28.
Any idea where this difference is coming from?

BTW, I'm not concerned about the timezone. I just need a timestamp

**Update 1:**
The very same thing happens also when using Java 6 (which is the actual version used within our production environment in Brazil).
So, the problem does not depend on the java version

**Update 2:**
The problem does not occur when entering a number of seconds below 441763200 (which corresponds to 01-01-1914 00:00:00)
The question remains why we get a difference for Brazil?

Comment: This is tagged as Java 8 and yet you're using the awful, outdated datetime classes. Use `java.time`.

Comment: Maybe it's something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance()` uses `TimeZone.getDefault()`. Try `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` instead

Comment: @Michael: within our production environment we're still using java-6. I updated the answer.

Comment: Since midnight 01-01-1900 in what time zone? Sorry, you cannot evade that question because the answer depends on it.

Comment: I have reproduced. When I set my JVM’s default time zone to America/Sao_Paulo, I get `3752388800 corresponds to 2018-11-28 11:19:48`.

Comment: @Meini When setting the timezone, I get rid of the strange difference but introduce a time shift due to the timezone. I can work on that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this site: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo and navigate to Time zone changes for: 1900-1924. There you can see an offset of -03:06:28 to UTC before 01-01-1914. It is exactly the same reason as in [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

### java.time

A solution is to make sure you do your conversion in UTC:

```
    Instant base = LocalDate.of(1900, Month.JANUARY, 1)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant();

    String secsSince1900String = "3752388800";
    long secsSince1900 = Long.parseLong(secsSince1900String);
    Instant target = base.plusSeconds(secsSince1900);
    System.out.println(target);
```

Output (independent of JVM time zone):

> 2018-11-28T10:13:20Z

The trailing `Z` in the output means UTC. I have tested while setting my JVM’s default time zone to America/Sao_Paulo, it made no difference. If you want, you can formate the date and time to your liking, for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDateTime = target.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

> 2018-11-28 10:13:20

### What went wrong when running in Brazil?

There are a number of time zones across Brazil. I took São Paulo as an example and reproduced your output readily. At the turn of the century in 1900, São Paulo was at offset -03:06:28 from GMT. Your `Calendar` uses the JVM’s default time zone, so you really set its time of day to 03:06:28 GMT, which explains the difference.

That said, the date-time classes you were using — `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` — have design problems and have fortunately been replaced by java.time, the modern Java date and time API, with Java 8 nearly 5 years ago. One trait of the modern API is we more naturally make time zone explicit, which makes it easier to avoid issues like yours, and also to fix them if we run into them anyway.

### Question: Our production Java version is Java 6. Can I use java.time?

Yes, java.time works nicely on Java 6. It has been backported.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I agree with your consideration regarding Java-8. Unfortunately I cannot change that within a production environment.

Comment: @RobertKock The original date-time classes are a bloody awful wretched mess. You really should consider adding the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project. The library includes a utilities class [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) for converting back-and-forth between the modern types and the legacy types. So you can still interoperate with your existing code base, no need to revamp all the date-time handling code at once. FYI: `Date` is replaced by `Instant`, `GregorianCalendar` by `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Thanks. I'll check this out for sure

Answer (score 3):

On Jan 1st, 1914 Brazil changed the time and added 6 minutes and 28 seconds to their time moving from LMT to BRT (see [Time Changes in São Paulo Over the Years, 1900-1924](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/sao-paulo?syear=1900)).

The additional one hour of difference is probably that Brazil spans 3 time zones (`UTC-4`, `UTC-3`, `UTC-2`) and you didn't set the time zone in your code, depending on the JVM system time zone.

Comment: This explains the difference. Together with Meini's comment, I can solve the problem.